# Two-line spacing between comments

Tags: support

There is a two-line spacing between comments. But if I upvote any comment, the spacing gets reduced to single-line spacing. Why is this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because there needs to be space to display all the options you can do to a comment.

Before upvoting, it needs to display both the up arrow and the flag option.

[image]

And after upvoting:

[image]

There is no need for that extra space.